# AJAX POST Request not working in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

While trying to use ajax request in my application using Laravel 5.6 I've found that the ajax request is not triggering.

**My Controller code**

```
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    function index(Request $request)
    {
        $msg = "Sample Messgae";
        return response()->json(['msg' => $msg)]);
    }
}
```

**The Route,**

web.php

```
Route::post('/message','AjaxController@index');
Route::get('/sample','UserRedirectController@ajaxRedirect');
```

**The view**

```
<input type="text" name="ajax" id="ajax">
<input type="text" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" id="token" hidden>
<button id="save" onclick="ajaxRequestFun();">Show</button>
<span id="cont"></span>
```

**Finally the script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' :  $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });
    });
    functon ajaxRequestFun()
    {
        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/message',
        data : {'_token': {{csrf_token()}} },
        success:function(res){
            alert("success");
        }
        });
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: try to put your bind with jQuery in your document ready like : `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#save').click(function(){ ajaxRequestFun() }); });`

Comment: No effect, nothing happening while clicking Save button

Comment: did you remove the onclick in your html ?

Comment: Yes I did but the error remains the same

Comment: Are you using middleware of laravel in same controller?

Comment: $this->middleware('ajax-request', ['except' => ['PUT_YOUR_AJAX_FUNCTION_NAME']]);

Comment: what error displayed ??

Comment: Have you attempted any debugging of this issue? Is the issue with the JS, for example? Use your browser developer tools to see if the request is even being sent. If you do this debugging yourself and narrow down the issue, you are far more likely to get a helpful answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found some solution,
I've just added a meta tag to the view head tag just like.

```
<meta name="token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

then at the JavaScript side formed the data to send using,

```
var pass= {'_token':$('meta[name="token"]').attr('content'),
            'MessageContent': document.getElementById("message").value,
        };
```

and initiated the ajax call normally with **data:** parameter as variable **pass** which I've created,
My ajax code is something like,

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{{url("/message")}}',
        datatype:'json',
        data: pass,
        success:function(data){
            $("#bubble").html(data);
        }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
```

what I've found important is,

> Use of the meta tag with the csrf_token() key

what else is as same as that of the other frameworks,